# Changing computed property in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, computed-properties

I'm having NSFetchedResultsController as lazy computed property.
Based on a variable, sort descriptor is created. Here's my code:

```
private var sortOption: Options = .none
fileprivate lazy var inspirationsResults: NSFetchedResultsController<Inspiration> = {
    // Create Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Inspiration> = Inspiration.fetchRequest()

    // Configure Fetch Request
    //let optn = self.sortOption.rawValue
    switch (self.sortOption) {
    case .sortAscending:
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "inspirationName", ascending: true)]
    case .sortDescending:
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "inspirationName", ascending: false)]
    case .sortByAdding:
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)]
    case .sortByUpdated:
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)]
    case .showFilter:
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)]
    default:
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)]
    }
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)]
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 10
    // Create Fetched Results Controller
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: CoreDataManager.shared.getContext(), sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    // Configure Fetched Results Controller
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

When sortOption variable's value is changed, I want to recompute "inspirationsResults" variable and change the sort descriptor accordingly. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the code to compute the sort descriptor into the `didSet` observer of the `sortOption` property:

```
private var sortOption: Options = .none {
    didSet {
        let sortDescriptor : NSSortDescriptor
        switch sortOption {
            case .sortAscending:
                sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "inspirationName", ascending: true)
            case .sortDescending:
                sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "inspirationName", ascending: false)
            default:
                sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
         }
         fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
         do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            tableView.reloadData()
         } catch {
            print(error)
         }
    }
}
```

The `default` case covers all explicit cases which sort by `timeStamp - false`.
After changing the sort descriptor you need to perform a new fetch and reload the table view.

And in the method to initialize the results controller simply write:

```
self.sortOption = .none
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a property declared as lazy can't be changed once it's set.

You can create the same thing yourself using a property with a custom getter that returns a private property that's created if it's nil. Have the setter for sortOption set the private property to nil to force it to be recalculated.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the declaration of `inspirationsResults` to be an implicitly unwrapped optional

```
fileprivate lazy var inspirationsResults: NSFetchedResultsController<Inspiration>! = { ...
```

...then you can force it to reinitialize by setting its value to nil. As in, if you set `inspirationsResults` to nil, then the next time you access it, the initialization code runs again. Using an implicitly unwrapped optional is safe here as long as your initialization code never returns nil.

You could then set `inspirationResults` to nil in the `didSet` observer for `sortOption`. The next time you use `inspirationResults` you'll get a new version with new sorting.

Comment: You don't need to reinitialize the fetched results controller, you just need to change the sort descriptor.

Comment: Changing the sort descriptor will have no useful effect. The fetched results controller won't automatically update its results.

Comment: Right. Of course you have to perform a fetch after changing the sort descriptor. I updated my answer.